# How to use promises so that loop doesn't hang

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am trying to loop through records in a database, in order to compile an array (cardsToInsert) that I will write to another database.

I was getting stuck because the array was writing to the database before the loop finished, I know I need to use promises / async functions to achieve what I want, but I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong with my promises.

The code works for a few loops (it goes for about 6-10 loops, it's supposed to loop 16 times), but then hangs while trying during wixData.get (or it hangs on a different promise that is part of buildCard).

```
// wixData.get is a function that returns a promise

async function loopCards(cardsToGet) {
    let writeCard
    let buildCard
    for (let index = 0; index < cardsToGet.length; index++) {

        const cardToGet = cardsToGet[index].card
        buildCard = await wixData.get("Card", cardToGet)
            .then((card) => {
                return card
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                let errorMsg = err;
                return errorMsg
            });
        writeCard = await buildingCard(buildCard)
        cardsToInsert.push(writeCard)
    }
    return cardsToInsert
}
```

What am I doing wrong? (or what is the key thing I'm doing wrong that is stopping this working, I'm sure there is plenty to be improved here!)

**UPDATE**

I've now updated the code and it loops through fine.

```
async function loopCards(cardsToGet) {
console.log('Start')
let writeCard
let buildCard

for (let index = 0; index < cardsToGet.length; index++) {

    const cardToGet = cardsToGet[index].card
    buildCard = wixData.get("Card", cardToGet)
        .then(async (card) => {
            writeCard = await buildingCard(card)
            cardsToInsert.push(writeCard)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            let errorMsg = err;
            return errorMsg
        });

}
return cardsToInsert
}
```

How do I get it to wait for the loop to finish before finally returning cardsToInsert?

Comment: could there be a rate limit on the API you are using? assuming it's  external API?

Comment: by the way, using async/await AND .then in the same function is not considered best practice - and `.then((card) => {
                return card
            })` is as useful as `function(x) { return x}`

Comment: and, do you really want to `buildingCard(buildCard)` when `wixData.get` rejects?

Comment: Well, which is it?  Does it hang in `wixData.get` or hang in `buildCard`?  Maybe you should debug it?  Or at least stick in some console.logs messages to trace execution?

Comment: does `buildingCard` return a Promise? correctly? Is there any error indicated in the browser **developer** tools console? (assuming this is browser code of course)

Comment: I suspect that `buildingCard` is the problem, that it is your code, and you create and return a Promise that is never settled (i.e. neither resolved or rejected) - the code isn't hanging, it's just waiting on a pending promise - possibly because of a mis-handled error condition in your `wixData.get` code

Comment: we can't help you if you don't clarify your issue - please respond to comments asking for such clarification

Comment: I've improved the code on your suggestion @JaromandaX and put it in the original question. How do I get it to wait for the loop to finish before returning cardsToInsert?

Comment: oh, so it wasn't the rate of API calls, it was making the second call when there was an error in the first?

Comment: to answer the supplementary question ... `await wixData.get`

Comment: "oh, so it wasn't the rate of API calls, it was making the second call when there was an error in the first?" Correct

Comment: @JaromandaX you answer to the supplementary question. `await wixData.get` is already inside the loop, how will that help?

Comment: @mrpowergage - not in the final code you posted - `buildCard = wixData.get("Card", cardToGet)` no await there - this is why you don't mix `await` with `then` - it looks confusing - read my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mix of `async/await` and `.then` is not really *best practice*

This should work, and will return once cardsToInsert is populated

```
async function loopCards(cardsToGet) {
    const cardsToInsert = [];
    for (let cardToGet of cardsToGet) {
        try {
            const card = await wixData.get("Card", cardToGet);
            const writeCard = await buildingCard(card);
            cardsToInsert.push(writeCard);
        }
        catch(err) {
            let errorMsg = err;
            return errorMsg;
        }
    }
    return cardsToInsert;
}
```

better still, you really don't need to handle any errors here, since the calling function could do that

So it becomes even simpler

```
async function loopCards(cardsToGet) {
    const cardsToInsert = [];
    for (let cardToGet of cardsToGet) {
        const card = await wixData.get("Card", cardToGet);
        const writeCard = await buildingCard(card);
        cardsToInsert.push(writeCard);
    }
    return cardsToInsert;
}
```

then using it could be like

```
loopCards(cards)
.then(result => doSomethingWihtResult)
.catch(error => handleError);
```

or if calling from an async function

```
try {
    let result = await loopCards(cards);
    // do something with result
} catch(error) {
    // handle Error
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @JaromanadaX I'm still struggling to get this to work. `wixData.get("Card", cardToGet)` returns a promise, so am I right in thinking I shouldn't use await with this?

Comment: no, you're wrong ... you SHOULD use await on a function returning a Promise - that is what await was designed for